# How to add <select> to theme header from plugin?

Tags: wordpress

How to add drop down option (`<select>`) in theme header (frontend). Just like the option to select language among available languages on sites with multi-language support.

But instead of making changes in theme, is it possible to add it from plugin through some hook?

I have in mind to add a function, and register its shortcode to be added in theme, but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1> Register a function to be executed when the wp_head action fires:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_function');
```

2> Make the function echo whatever you want in the header:

```
function my_function()
{
echo '<select> <option>1</option> </select>';
}
```